# Why my delta lake table is not collecting statistics (min, max values)?

Tags: apache-spark, indexing, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Using delta lake on azure databricks 7.4.

I am trying to understand optimization, ZORDER and data skipping. I want to use ZORDER BY on the business date column : `request_date_id` (data type is integer). I understood that for implementing zorder, the targeted column should have delta statistics.

While my column `request_date_id` is in field number 7, it seems that my table does not have collected statistics on it

[image]

The table does have different distinct `request_date_id`. Why no statistics have been collected ?

[image]

It seems to me that [data skipping](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/dataskipping-index.html) options have been removed from databricks 7 onwards. But according to what i understood, it is still default. Delta lake table should still be collecting statistics.

Any suggestion or guidance would be very much appreciated. Many thanks in advance  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was removed in DBR 7.x is a special type of indexes implemented on the SQL level.  But the Delta has [built-in data skipping](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt.html#data-skipping) independent of if data registered as SQL table or just saved on disk.  You can check that by looking into `_delta_log/NNNNNN.json` files, for each added file, there will be `stats` field, with min/max values for indexed columns. For example: `{"add": {"path": "part-00002-d0b474c0-6b00-4bef-9fbb-de97e157e199-c000.snappy.parquet", "partitionValues": {}, "size": 134637, "modificationTime": 1628835148000, "dataChange": true, "stats": "{\"numRecords\":33333, \"minValues\":{\"id\":1}, \"maxValues\":{\"id\":99997}, \"nullCount\": {\"id\":0}}"}}`